# Calculate days from date

Tags: apex, trigger

I'm looking a way to calculate the days....this is what the requirement:

If the `CalendarInterval` is 90 days and `LastCompletionDate` is 04/05/2015 then find the # of days.

Here is what I have gathered.

```
  String CalendarInterval = 90; //days;
  Date daysDiff = CalendarInterval - LastCompletionDate; //04/05/2015 
  If the DaysDiff >= 90 {
      //create entry in Order Object
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

90 days from when? I guess from today/now? If that's the case then you can use the [`daysBetween`](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_date.htm#apex_System_Date_daysBetween) method and calculate that easily:

```
Date startDate = LastCompletionDate;
Date dueDate = System.today();
Integer daysBetween = startDate.daysBetween(dueDate);
if (daysBetween >= CalendarInterval)
{
    // your code
}
```